# «Военная форма одежды»

Tags: словосочетания

Зачем в этом словосочетании нужно слово *одежды*? *Военная форма* — это и так одежда. Кто-нибудь может объяснить? Или это всё-таки плеоназм и его следует убрать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Форма одежды — обычное словосочетание.**

Это повседневная форма одежды, которая марается, изнашивается и быстро выходит из строя.

Форма одежды спортивная.

Под европейский менталитет была разработана форма одежды участников: куртка с короткими рукавами, подпоясанная поясом, трусы (обтягивающее трико) и ботинки на мягкой подошве.

**2) Официальный стиль.**

Вооруженные силы перейдут на абсолютно новую форму одежды с 2014 года.

**3) Нейтральный стиль** (слово *одежда* опущено)**:**

Военная форма сидит ловко, аккуратно.

Ему военная форма сильно идёт.

Answer (score 4):

В уставе ВС РФ есть такое понятие как "форма одежды", по которому определяется, как можно и как нельзя носить военную форму. Поэтому словосочетание "военная форма одежды" в принципе возможно, но надо знать контекст.